# Kibana histogram with a bucket size of 1 on the x axis

Tags: kibana

I've a bunch of data in ES that I'm looking to visualize in Kibana. I have 1000 different products and a percentage stock level of each one, updated every minute. In my index I thus have productcode and stocklevel. In any given period (e.g. last hour) I'd like to know which products have dipped below 80% of maximum stock level

In Visualize, I've set the Y axis to be MIN(StockPercentage) and the X axis to be a Histogram of the product code. It works, but kibana is automatically choosing the bucket size for the x axis and on this particular graph it's somewhere around 25 product codes per bucket. I thus get the minimum stock level of any of the 25 products in the bucket which does help narrow it down, but I was hoping for a graph that can tell me with an aggregation precision per product (i.e. no aggregation)

I've also looked at doing a Range agg of the ProductCode but it looks like i'll have to add 1000 ranges (1 to 2, 2 to 3...) to get the product codes to show up, and that's a lot of ranges

How can I make a graph that doesn't do any aggregation of product codes and just draws a bar line per product code?